# Button click gives error message if input field is empty in react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Now I would need your help with a simple validation:
if input field is empty when I click a button I want a message to pop up. I want the message to disappear when the field is filled in.

with this code

```
if (number.trim().length === 0) {
      return;
    }
```

I prevent any action to take place, but the user don´t get any error message.
I come up with:

```
const [errors, setErrors] = useState([]);

const isRequired = (number) => {
  return number.trim().length > 0 ? '' : 'Please enter scorers number';
};
const validate = (validations) => {
    setErrors(validations.map((err) => err(number)));
  };

{errors.length > 0 ? <h4 style={{color: 'red'}}>{errors}</h4> : null}
```

but how can I make the message show and hide?
I guess I have to attach to the onClick?

My whole code:

````
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {useState} from 'react';
import {New} from './New';
const isRequired = (number) => {
  return number.trim().length > 0 ? '' : 'Please enter scorers number';
};

const App = () => {
  const [number, setNumber] = useState('');
  const [totPoints, setTotPoints] = useState(0);
  const [scorers, setScorers] = useState([]);
  const [focused, setFocused] = useState(false);
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState([]);

  const validate = (validations) => {
    setErrors(validations.map((err) => err(number)));
  };

  const sortedScorers = [...scorers].sort((a, b) => a.number - b.number);

  const onePointScoredHandler = () => {
    const players = [...scorers];
    if (number.trim().length === 0) {
      return;
    }
    const pos = players.map((player) => player.number).indexOf(+number);

    if (pos !== -1) {
      console.log('exist');
      setScorers((scorers) =>
        scorers.map((scorer, index) =>
          index === pos
            ? {
                ...scorer,
                totPoints: scorer.totPoints + 1,
              }
            : scorer
        )
      );
    } else {
      console.log('new');
      const newScorer = {
        id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000),
        number: +number,
        totPoints: totPoints + 1,
      };

      setScorers([...scorers, newScorer]);
      setTotPoints(totPoints);
    }
    setNumber('');
    console.log(scorers);
  };

  const twoPointScoredHandler = () => {
    if (number.trim().length === 0) {
      return;
    }
    const players = [...scorers];

    const pos = players.map((player) => player.number).indexOf(+number);

    if (pos !== -1) {
      console.log('exist');
      setScorers((scorers) =>
        scorers.map((scorer, index) =>
          index === pos
            ? {
                ...scorer,
                totPoints: scorer.totPoints + 2,
              }
            : scorer
        )
      );
    } else {
      console.log('new');
      const newScorer = {
        id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000),
        number: +number,
        totPoints: totPoints + 2,
      };
      setScorers([...scorers, newScorer]);
      setTotPoints(totPoints);
    }
    setNumber('');
    console.log(scorers);
  };
  const threePointScoredHandler = () => {
    if (number.trim().length === 0) {
      return;
    }
    const players = [...scorers];

    const pos = players.map((player) => player.number).indexOf(+number);

    if (pos !== -1) {
      console.log('exist');
      setScorers((scorers) =>
        scorers.map((scorer, index) =>
          index === pos
            ? {
                ...scorer,
                totPoints: scorer.totPoints + 3,
              }
            : scorer
        )
      );
    } else {
      console.log('new');
      const newScorer = {
        id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000),
        number: +number,
        totPoints: totPoints + 3,
      };
      setScorers([...scorers, newScorer]);
      setTotPoints(totPoints);
    }
    setNumber('');
    console.log(scorers);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h4>Individual points</h4>
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
      <input
        type="number"
        value={number}
        placeholder="scorer number"
        onChange={(e) => setNumber(e.target.value)}
        onFocus={() => setFocused(true)}
        onBlur={() => {
          setFocused(false);
        }}
      />
      {errors.length > 0 ? <h4 style={{color: 'red'}}>{errors}</h4> : null}
      <br />
      <br />
      <button onClick={(onePointScoredHandler, validate([isRequired]))}>
        1p scored
      </button>
      <button onClick={twoPointScoredHandler}>2p scored</button>
      <button onClick={threePointScoredHandler}>3p scored</button>
      <br />
      <br />

      {scorers.length ? (
        <table className="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>player NUMBER</th>
              <th>Total Points</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {sortedScorers
              .sort((a, b) => a.number - b.number)
              .map((player) => (
                <tr key={player.id}>
                  <td>{player.number}</td>
                  <td>{player.totPoints}</td>
                </tr>
              ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      ) : (
        <New />
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;

```
Thanks in advance
/Peter
````

Comment: Please create a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

a couple things I noted and thought I'll share my thoughts with you.

1. It is easier for you and for other developers if you structure functionality etc. in own components so that like here, your `<App/>` isn't that bloated.
2. `{errors.length > 0 ? <h4 style={{color: 'red'}}>{errors}</h4> : null}` this is an unnecessary ternary, you can just use `{errors.length && <h4 style={{color: 'red'}}>{errors}</h4>`
3. You should post your error message that you are getting and explain what you do not understand about it. I think I know the problem, but I don't like guessing.

Comment: thanks:)
It's the next step, after I've made it work the way I want it to.
error message: Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

Comment: The error only occurs when you have this `<button onClick={(onePointScoredHandler, validate([isRequired]))}>
        1p scored
      </button>` instead of this `<button onClick={(onePointScoredHandler)}>
        1p scored
      </button>` is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

you should use

```
setTimeout(() =>{
  setErors('')
},5000)
```

you message will automatically disappear after 5 se`enter code here`c.**strong text**